# Unable to create docker secret with STDIN

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a docker secret on Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS.

I have created a swarm using `docker swarm init`.

When I run `echo "my_secret" | docker secret create my_secret - someSecret`, I get an error:

```
"docker secret create" requires at least 1 and at most 2 arguments.
See 'docker secret create --help'.

Usage:  docker secret create [OPTIONS] SECRET [file|-] [flags]

Create a secret from a file or STDIN as content
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have just discovered that a secret can be created without the `echo` part of the command.
Run `docker create secret my_secret -`, then you then add secret paramater, then press Ctrl-D and the secret is created.

Comment: Just run `echo "my_secret" | docker create secret my_secret -`

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman, running that command creates the secret without me specifying a paramater for it.

Comment: You can also check the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret_create/#create-a-secret-with-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret create command takes up to two parameters, the secret name, and optionally where to read the secret from. The `-` says to read from stdin. You provided 3 arguments, which isn't valid, `my_secret`, `-`, and `someSecret`

```
echo "someSecret" | docker create secret my_secret -
```

That will create a secret named `my_secret` with the value `someSecret`.

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` command by default adds an extra newline character at the end. Which will also affect your secret. You have to add the `-n` option, which forces echo not to output the trailing newline.

```
echo -n "someSecret" | docker create secret my_secret -
```

Comment: This is the way to go, `printf` also an option.

Comment: I have tried all suggestions here, but I am still seeing that the secret mounted into the container has a CTRL + LF at the end.
I am deploying the secret like this from powershell core:

```
 $passVal = $pass.value.Trim()
 echo -n "$passVal" | docker secret create $dockerSecretOrConfigName -
```

Comment: so i am quite sure that your env var has a appending cr/lf